# Cassandra querying a text value with space in shell

Tags: utf-8, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm having an issue trying to querying my database, my script with cassandra-driver was this:

```
const query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.RestaurantMenuItems ' +
  '(id UUID, restaurantId varchar, menuName text, menuCategoryNames text, menuItemName text, menuItemDescription text, menuItemPrice decimal, PRIMARY KEY (id))';
return client.execute(query);
```

I have no idea how I could query with the spaces involved.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HU9b.png

Answer (score 1):

With that schema you can only do selects on `id`, not restaurantId id. To satisfy that query C* would have to read the entire dataset from every node. If that is a query you will want to make your table would likely be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.items_by_restaurant (
  restaurant_id varchar,
  menu_name text,
  menu_category_name text,
  menu_item_name text,
  menu_item_description text,
  menu_item_price decimal,
  PRIMARY KEY ((restaurantId), menu_name, menu_category_name, menu_item_name)
);
```

Comment: I'm okay with that but I was just wondering why the shell command won't read space ' ' as a space. If I query any other text value without a space, it would query and return me everything I need.

Comment: The schema and query is cause of your error not the space.

Answer (score 1):

As per your screen shot, this is not an issue of text with space. If you add a space in a text it will be count as a character like others. As @Chris mentioned earlier, you are querying with a column which is not a partition key or not indexed. You need to use ALLOW FILTERING in your query to get data which is not recommended. Try creating index on the column you want to query with.

```
create index on restaurantmenuitems (restaurantid) ;
```

I am attaching a screen shot.  [image]